# Avoid implicit conversion in SQL Server procedure params

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PrintScreen
       @text as varchar(2000)
AS
BEGIN
       PRINT @text
END
GO

EXEC PrintScreen @text = Hello    --I want this sentence fail
GO

EXEC PrintScreen @text = 'Hello'
go

DROP PROCEDURE PrintScreen
GO
```

Why I can call PrintScreen procedure withnow quotes?

Exist any option to change this behavior?

Comment: This is the only context in which an unquoted string is interpreted as a string AFAIK. It is unambiguous here but still somewhat inconsistent and I guess just there for backward compatibility. [The docs state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188332.aspx) "If the value of a parameter is a ... character string ... the whole name must be enclosed in single quotation marks". And don't advertise this isnt't required if no embedded spaces

Comment: There does not seem to be any switch to change this behavior. And as [microsoft itself says](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/278399/parameter-assignment-to-unquoted-string): `If we could go back and start over, we'd probably take your advice and make quoting consistent. Unfortunately, this is very widely used legacy behavior that needs to be maintained for compatibility reasons.`

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this BTW? Has it actually caused a problem?

Comment: Martin, I need prevent calls in other procedures like: CREATE PROCEDURE SomeScreen @text as varchar(2000) AS exec PrintScreen text

Comment: Yes, we got that, but why? Does it cause you any troubles or are you just not pleased aesthetically?

Comment: I need prevent this mistake: CREATE PROCEDURE SomeScreen @text as varchar(2000) AS exec PrintScreen text  sometimes people that work with oracle forgot @

Comment: Instead of trying to prevent perhaps you can just look for evidence of the implicit conversion in the plan cache: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/01/08/finding-implicit-column-conversions-in-the-plan-cache.aspx

Comment: @nathan That won't work because it isn't actually an implicit conversion despite the question title here.

Comment: @MartinSmith ah, yes. You're right.